# How to make Camel route Exchange to retrieve original data type?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Im executing Camel route which receives body/parameter from `FluentProducerTemplate` using `withBody(parameter)` and then in a r
oute I want to execute `carService(CarReg carReg)` method into which I want to pass parameter which I have sent from producer.

Route is working, when I am testing it with executing method which doesnt required parameter and then called method and route return requested data.
Also the body/parameter Im sending is correctly passed into route exchange since in debug mode I can see that exchange holds correct data I have passed.

The issue is when I want in an exchange to call method into which I want to pass parameter which is supposed to be retrieved by the exchange, then this code is flagged as an error `getCarDetails(exchange.getIn().getBody))` stating that Im passing just `Object` and not required `CarReg` object type.
How to ensure that parameter retrieved by the exchange is of the original type and not an Object type?

```
 @EndpointInject
 private FluentProducerTemplate fProducerTemplate

  public CarDetails startRoute(CarReg carReg){
    CarDetails carDetails = fProducerTemplate.withBody(carReg)
       .to("direct:route") 
       .request(CarDetails .class)  
  }

@Override
public void configure() throw Exception
   from("direct:route")
      .process(exchange -> {
         exchange.getIn().getBody();    //exchange correctly retrieves passed parameter              
        
         exchange.get().setBody(carService.getCarDetails(exchange.getIn().getBody));
       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I hope this should work.

```
       @Override
    public void configure() throw Exception
    from("direct:route")
      .process(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().getBody();    //exchange correctly retrieves passed parameter

        exchange.get().setBody(carService.getCarDetails(exchange.getIn().getBody((CarReg.class))));
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work by declaring it as class `getBody((CarReg.class))`.There must be other way to  somehow cast to the appropriate class. 
Called method looks like this  `public ResponseEntity<CarDetails> getBody(CarReg.class)`  returns value as  `ResponseEntity`. Not sure if this makes any difference to the way method is called  and the way the response is recieved.

Answer (score 1):

Message.getBody() has an overload that takes a class as parameter. So:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(carService.getCarDetails(exchange.getIn().getBody(CarReg.class)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type case it using Jackson library as well

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

String body = exchange.getIn().getBody();

CarReg carReg = objectMapper.convertValue( body , CarReg.class );
```